# Why is the following || skipping the valid value?

Tags: javascript

The following code sets `this.statOffset` base on the existence of first and child nodes:

```
console.log('Node: ', this.node.childNodes.item(0))
console.log('Node length: ', this.node.childNodes.item(0).length)

this.startOffset = this.node.length - 1 ||
    this.node.firstChild.length - 1 || 
    this.node.childNodes.item(0).length - 1 || 
    this.node.childNodes.item(0).firstChild.length - 1
```

It works okay. But in some cases I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null` in the last value: `this.node.childNodes.item(0).firstChild.length - 1`

Strangely, this happens when `this.node.childNodes.item(0).length - 1` is the valid value. The `console.logs` output:

```
Node: "a"
Node lenght: 1
```

Why is the code skipping the valid value and trying to execute the last one (which is an invalid one)?

**EDIT:** Structure of the nodes:

```
<p>
    <strong>a</strong>
    b
    <span>
        <em>c</em>
    </span>
    d
    <strong>e</strong>
</p>
```

Comment: Probably because [of how negative numbers are cast to booleans](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xus1Z.png) - you should make a fiddle or put [runnable js](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in your question so users can see, rather than read, what's happening.

Comment: `this.node.length - 1` will evaluate to `false` when the `length` is 1 (0 == false). So your code will run and hit the  `this.node.childNodes.item(0).firstChild.length`. Which makes `firstChild` `undefined`, causing the exception.

Comment: Also element doesn't have length property. Use `children` or `childNodes` instead

Comment: I'd also consider to use node.hasChildNodes() instead of `length - 1` checks. [MDN resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/hasChildNodes).

Answer (score 1):

> It works okay. But in some cases I get an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'length' of null in the last value:
>   this.node.childNodes.item(0).firstChild.length - 1

Two things

1. You don't need to reduce 1 from length otherwise it will only work if length is greater than 1 or 0.
2. You need to use `childNodes` or `children` rather than length since [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) doesn't have length property

Assuming that `this` refers to the element on which event has happened, try

```
 this.startOffset = this.childNodes.length ||
   this.childNodes.item(0).childNodes.length;
```

Or by using `hasChildNodes`

```
 this.startOffset = this.hasChildNodes() ||
   this.childNodes.item(0).hasChildNodes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried children instead of childNodes? This can be helpful while seelcting the children, even when we try this on different browsers, children seems to work on all but childNodes doesn't work for all.

Both works differently sometimes. I've worked on IPad and I've done some work with childNodes and that wasn't working on that.

```
<html>
    <div id="div1">
      <div id="div2">
        <div id="div3">
          <div id="div4">
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
<script>
    var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
    console.log(div1.childNodes.item(0).firstChild);
    console.log(div1.children.item(0).firstChild)
    document.getElementById("div4").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(div1.childNodes.item(0).firstChild);
    document.getElementById("div4").innerHTML += div1.children.item(0).firstChild;
</script>
<html>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3934/)